# API Goal Creation Limit

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I want to programatically set a few goals for each **trackingId** I create. 
The docs say:

> Also you can create at most 20 goals through the API; see the limits
>   and quotas page for details.

It is unclear to me:

1. limit across all trackingIds (i.e. I have twenty trackingIds, I can create one goal for each trackingId with the API)
2. Limit 20 goals created per trackingId via API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goals are view based.

You have a Tracking id (web property) under that property you have one ore more a view / profile.   Each view / profile can have up to 20 goals.

You could just make additional views under your web property and have additional goals.    You can not analyze data across views though.

This is not really API related this is how Google Analytics works.

You can also get a [professional Google Analytics account](https://www.google.dk/analytics/360-suite/analytics/#?modal_active=none) I believe the limit is higher.